# Model theoretic answer for having algebraic closure

Tags: field-theory, model-theory

I am beginner at the model theory and I learn compactness theorem at the class and I saw 
some application of it and one of them is that "every field has an algebraic closure". How can I prove it with compactness theorem ?

Comment: Why not try to do it yourself?

Comment: Start with stating what you know about fields and field extensions

Comment: @fgp i know it's proof from standart way ( constructing it's extension ) and i am okey with fields and fields extension .

Comment: The basic idea is that you use algebra to conclude that you can adjoin finitly many zeros to a field without running into problems. The compactness theorem then allows you to adjoin them all at once by adding suitable axioms that force their existance. You know that the resulting theory is consistent, because if it wasn't, some finite subset would already have to be inconsistent, which is isn't per the above. Since the theory is consistent, it has a model, and that model is then the algebraic closure...

Comment: @fgp: not exactly. The model of the theory can be any field *containing* the algebraic closure.

Comment: @tomasz Yeah, I should have put this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a field $F$, start by using the compactness theorem to show that there exists a field extension $F^*$ of $F$ such that every nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$ has a root in $F^*$. (When applying compactness, you should be considering a theory over a language that includes constants for the elements of $F$.)

What happens when you iterate this process?

Comment: it is clear that if i prove what you said i can finish the whole proof but i have two thing that i can't understand , what should be my theory to show F[x] has a root in F* ? Also it is not clear to me why you need to add constants to your language is it to say  "every nonconstant polynomial in F[x]" ?

Comment: The theory to consider is the theory of fields (with the same characteristic as $F$) and then, for each nonconstant polynomial $p(x)$ in $F[x]$, you add a sentence stating "$p$ has a root". Unless you add constants to your language, there's no way to refer to $p$ explicitly.

Comment: If you're going to iterate the process anyway, why bother applying compactness at all? Why not just add the roots in one at a time? What actual benefit does compactness have on the proof?